# В чем разница между внешним ключом и индексом mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

В чем разница между внешним ключом и индексом `mysql`
и как это связанно с join запросами ?

Comment: Индекс - "внутренняя" структура таблицы. Внешний ключ - ссылка "наружу", на вторую таблицу. С JOIN - никак не связано, ни то, ни другое.

Comment: Внешний ключ - это инструмент для обеспечения целостности данных, их непротиворечивости. Индекс - это инструмент обеспечивающий быстрый поиск и так же использующийся для обеспечения внешних ключей. А join - это элемент языка который позволяет объявить по каким принципам соединять таблицы, ни к первому ни ко второму никакого отношения не имеющий, но могущий использовать индекс как инструмент